# Inserting an attribute in all nodes of a xml using xml.modify

Tags: sql-server

I need to read the whole xml one by one and then add attribute in every node of xml. Any idea how can I do this. I dont want to change the actuall xml. Just for the run time.

Comment: I would write a utility for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the XML you can use the [insert XML DML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175466.aspx).

```
UPDATE Table
SET xml_column = xml_column.modify('
  insert <foo>Some Text</foo>
  as first
  into (/some/path)[1]')
```

Note that .modify() can only appear in a update context (ie. an UPDATE statement or an SET statement), it cannot appear in a SELECT context.

If you want to project a modified XML *without* alering the actual XML in the database then you should not use the XML DML methods, but instead use XQuery and the [.query()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) method. XQuery allows you to build on-the-fly a new XML based on the original XML, including adding new elements and attributes.